# Apache Ignite not resolving properties in configuration XML

Tags: spring, properties, ignite

I am looking to load a number of values into my server configuration.xml from a properties file.
However, on adding the placeholders I start getting, property cannot be resolved errors. Preferably I would like to use Jasypt, which has loaded up fine, but has the same issue, property cannot be resolved.

Sample placeholder:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="ignite.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Sample Bean:

```
<property name="sslContextFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory">
        <property name="keyStoreFilePath" value="ignite.jks"/>
        <property name="keyStorePassword" value="${some.password}"/>
        <property name="keyStoreType" value="JKS"/>
        <property name="protocol" value="TLSv1.2"/>        
        <property name="trustManagers">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory" factory-method="getDisabledTrustManager"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Is it possible, is there a library I should have added, it otherwise runs fine if I do not use properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration is parsed by Spring and Ignite has nothing to do with it. I believe there are two possible reasons:

- Incorrect file path. Note that if the file is on the classpath, the location should be `classpath:ignite.properties`.
- Incorrect property name.

Comment: I was going to say that is not the issue, as I had fully qualified path names in for the values when I started. However, went back and tried again just now, restoring fully qualified paths and up it came. Must have been the file  permissions I changed earlier which was affecting the loading of the configuration file.